# How do I save custom functions and parameters in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Firstly, the network function is defined：

```
def softmax(X):
    X_exp=torch.exp(X)
    partition=X_exp.sum(1,keepdim=True)
    return X_exp/partition

def net(X):
    return softmax(torch.matmul(X.reshape(-1,W.shape[0]),W)+b)
```

Then update the function parameters by training

```
train(net,train_iter,test_iter,cross_entropy,num_epoches,updater)
```

Finally, the function is saved and loaded for prediction

```
PATH='./net.pth'
torch.save(net,PATH)
saved_net=torch.load(PATH)
predict(saved_net,test_iter,6)
```

**The prediction results show that the updated parameters W and b are not saved and loaded.
**What is the correct way to save custom functions and updated parameters ?****

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to implement your own [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) and then use the provided utilities to save and load the model's state (their weights) on demand.

You must define two functions:

- `__init__`: the class initializer logic where you define your model's parameters.
- `forward`: the function which implements the model's forward pass.

A minimal example would be of the form:

```
class LinearSoftmax(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_feat, out_feat):
        super().__init__()
        self.W = torch.rand(in_feat, out_feat)
        self.b = torch.rand(out_feat)

    def softmax(X):
        X_exp = torch.exp(X)
        partition = X_exp.sum(1, keepdim=True)
        return X_exp / partition

    def forward(X):
        return softmax(torch.matmul(X.reshape(-1,W.shape[0]),W)+b)
```

You can initialize a new model by doing:

```
>>> model = LinearSoftmax(10, 3)
```

You can then [save and load](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) weights `W` and `b` of a given instance:

- save the dictionary returned by [`nn.Module.state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=state_dict#torch.nn.Module.state_dict) with [`torch.save`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html):

  ```
  >>> torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
  ```
- load the weight into memory with [`torch.load`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html) and mount on model with [`nn.Module.load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=load_state_dict#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict)

  ```
  >>> model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
That is, torch. save only works for preserving tensor (or dic) or classes inherited from nn.Module, not for saving custom function parameters

Comment: @BuDiu Consider accepting the answer as valid if you found it helped you solve your question.